# How can I fix ugly XQuery output?

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

Here is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="student.xsl"?>
<Students xmlns="www.example.com"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="www.example.com student.xsd">
<Student>
    <SSN>622-12-5748</SSN>
    <Name>
        <First-Name>Alexander</First-Name>
        <Last-Name>Mart</Last-Name>
    </Name>
    <Age>26</Age>
    <Institution>UCSF</Institution>
    <Email>Alexander@yahoo.com</Email>
</Student>
</Students>
```

I have this XQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
declare namespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
declare default element namespace "http://www.example.com";

for $s in doc("student.xml")/Students/Student
let $firstName := $s/First-Name
let $lastName := $s/Last-Name
let $email := $s/Email
order by $lastName ascending
return 
<row>
    <first-name> { $firstName } </first-name>
    <last-name> { $lastName } </last-name>
    <email> { $email } </email>     
</row>
```

The output I am getting is:

```
<row xmlns="http://www.example.com">
    <first-name>
        <First-Name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   >Alexander</First-Name>
    </first-name>
    <last-name>
        <Last-Name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  >Mart</Last-Name>
    </last-name>
    <email>
        <Email xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              >Alexander@yahoo.com</Email>
    </email>
</row>
```

All the examples I see, though, output something like this:

```
<row>
    <first-name>Alexander</first-name>
    <last-name>Mart</last-name>
    <email>Alexander@yahoo.com</email>
</row>
```

How do I format my output prettily like this?

Also, why am I getting this

```
<First-Name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

tag in my results, instead of just `<first-name>`?  Is there a way to get rid of that?  I added the `declare default element namespace "http://www.example.com";` near the top because I couldn't get my XQuery to work without it.  But it would be really nice if that wasn't getting displayed in my results.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple solution and explanation.

Comment: Check my answer for an explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
declare namespace  x = "http://www.example.com";  

for $s in /x:Students/x:Student
  let $firstName := $s/x:First-Name/text()
    let $lastName := $s/x:Last-Name/text() 
      let $email := $s/x:Email/text() 
  order by $lastName ascending 
     return  
      <row>     
        <first-name> { $firstName } </first-name>     
        <last-name> { $lastName } </last-name>     
        <email> { $email } </email>      
      </row>
```

**when this is applied to the following XML document** (no XML document was provided by you!!!):

```
<Students  xmlns="http://www.example.com">
  <Student>
    <First-Name>A</First-Name>
    <Last-Name>Z</Last-Name>
    <Email>A.Z@T.com</Email>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<row>
   <first-name>A</first-name>
   <last-name>Z</last-name>
   <email>A.Z@T.com</email>
</row>
```

**Explanation**: The literal result elements (`row`, etc.) are in the default element namespace. The solution is not to use default element namespace declaration.

Comment: Oh wow, that did work.  Thanks so much!  Also, I went back and added my XML document to the top of the post.

Comment: So I am using XMLSpy to produce results.  It still outputs this as a single line of results, e.g. `<row><first-name>Goran</first-name><last-name>Alav</last-name><email>Goran@yahoo.com</email>`.  Am I not doing something to create create carriage returns so this all displays on its own line, or is that just the way XMLSpy displays it?  Do you know?

Comment: @steph: Serialization is an optional feature of XQuery and implementations are not required to implement it. Try specifying: `declare boundary-space preserve;`

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks for that.  It took me a few minutes to get that working because I was trying to put it below my namespace declarations, but once I moved it above those the file validated.  Now my output looks beautiful!  Thanks a bunch.  :)

Comment: @Dimitre:  Okay, one more question.  Now my last and first tag are showing up on the same line.  So between all my results I get `</row><row>` on the same line, even though everything else is getting put on its own line.  Is there a way to do a carriage return or something equivalent between each of my results, so that the `</row>` and `<row>` tags show up on separate rows?

Answer (score 0):

XQuery 1.0 does not have a standard way to request indentation (or other formatting) of results. Many XQuery implementations have their own mechanisms. For example, if you're using Saxon from the command line, you can use the option !indent=yes. I don't know what options XMLSpy provides.

There is an XQuery 1.0 option "declare boundary-space preserve" which causes whitespace in the query to be copied to the output; this might have the effect you require, though in my experience it can also have unwanted effects.

Answer (score 0):

First, your exact query shouldn't be producing that output. You must be using this instead (because of the **default namespace declaration on your input**):

```
declare namespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
declare namespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
declare namespace x = "www.example.com";
declare default element namespace "http://www.example.com";
for $s in /x:Students/x:Student
let $firstName := $s/x:Name/x:First-Name
let $lastName := $s/x:Name/x:Last-Name
let $email := $s/x:Email
order by $lastName ascending
return
<row>
     <first-name> { $firstName } </first-name>
     <last-name> { $lastName } </last-name>
     <email> { $email } </email>
</row>
```

That indeed output:

```
<row xmlns="http://www.example.com">
    <first-name>
        <First-Name xmlns="www.example.com"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   >Alexander</First-Name>
    </first-name>
    <last-name>
        <Last-Name xmlns="www.example.com" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  >Mart</Last-Name>
    </last-name>
    <email>
        <Email xmlns="www.example.com"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              >Alexander@yahoo.com</Email>
    </email>
</row>
```

**WHY?**: Because your sequence constructor `{ $firstName }` output the node instace referenciated by `$firstName` not its string-value. That should be:

```
declare namespace x = "www.example.com";
declare default element namespace "http://www.example.com";
for $s in /x:Students/x:Student
let $firstName := $s/x:Name/x:First-Name
let $lastName := $s/x:Name/x:Last-Name
let $email := $s/x:Email
order by $lastName ascending
return
<row>
     <first-name> { $firstName/string() } </first-name>
     <last-name> { string($lastName) } </last-name>
     <email> { normalize-space($email) } </email>
</row>
```

Output:

```
<row xmlns="http://www.example.com">
    <first-name>Alexander</first-name>
    <last-name>Mart</last-name>
    <email>Alexander@yahoo.com</email>
</row>
```